# pancreas lifetime and diabetes

Tags: diabetes, type-2-diabetes, pancreas

Reading an [old HE topic](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/13975/6615) about diabetes, I point out the words *"pancreatic exhaustion"*.

Does it mean the organ pancreas has a **lifetime**?

In other words, pancreas is able to produce insulin just for a certain amount of time and when it reaches its end-of-life, the Type 2 diabetes disease appears?

Comment: No. There are many factors. Vitamin A may help, but even so there is no one thing. https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/06/170613111649.htm Keep up your research. There is a proper role for sensible Viatmin A from diet, preferably. But it is a complicated disease.